# "getContext()" is working only in OnPaint event handler

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt5.3

I want to draw a line at a fix position in a `Canvas`.
I've written the following code:

```
function drawVLine(){
    var ctx1 = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx1.reset();
    ctx1.lineJoin = "round";

    ctx1.save()
    ctx1.lineWidth = 2
    ctx1.strokeStyle = "green"
    var x = 50
    ctx1.beginPath()
    ctx1.moveTo(x, 0)
    ctx1.lineTo(x, myCanvas.height)
    ctx1.stroke()
    ctx1.restore()
}
```

This code works properly when I call it from event handler `onPaint` but if I call this function through some other function, it does nothing.
I want to execute this function on certain signal and I don't want to call `myCanvas.requestPaint()` to trigger `onPaint` event and then draw the line.

Is it the case that `Context` can be fetched only from `onPaint` event?

**EDIT:**

according to comments and various attempts, I came to conclusion that, Painting methods can not be used out of `onPaint` events.

Comment: What problem to call this method from `onPaint`? This signal is emmited when `Canvas` has to be painted, so that exactly what you need. you can trigger rainting by  `markdirty()` or `requestPaint()`

Comment: @folibis I do lot of other things in `onPaint` and I don't want to repeat them for painting this line... So, I am searching for other way

Comment: Ma be you want to use `QQuickPaintedItem` instead of `Canvas`? So you will be able to use some cache operation etc.

Comment: I think you cannot use painting methods outside of `onPaint` just because it will be overwritten be calling `onPaint` when your `Canvas` need repaint

Comment: @folibis Yes... I also think so :-(

Comment: That's for sure: all painting actions must occur in the painting even handler. If you exploit [`markDirty`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html#markDirty-method) as suggested by @folibis you can use the passed parameter (`region`) to distinguish the specific paintings for your line from all the other paint actions. If the region is smaller than the whole canvas (it is) execute the line painting code. That is feasible depending on the current `onPaint` code, clearly.